# Why UITableView shows nil after scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

This code will fill the UITableView at first, but after scrolling all the labels show nil.
I persist the data in CoreData but it does't solve the problem.
I am guessing the problem is the UITableView
How should I fix the problem?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    Alamofire.request(.POST, url, parameters: nil, encoding: .URL, headers: ["username": "dsc", "password" : "cdsc"] ).responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .Success(let JSON):

            let response = JSON as! NSDictionary
            let jsonArray = response.objectForKey("data") as! NSArray

            for jsonObject in jsonArray {

                let name = jsonObject.objectForKey("name") as! String
                let percentage = NSNumber(double: (jsonObject.objectForKey("percentage")?.doubleValue)!)
                let quantity = NSNumber(int: (jsonObject.objectForKey("quantity")?.intValue)!)
                let managedObjectContext = stack.managedObjectContext
                let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Product", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)

                let product = Product(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)
                product.name = name
                product.percentage = percentage
                product.quantity = quantity
            }

            try! stack.managedObjectContext.save()

            let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Product")

            do {
                let result = try stack.managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)

                for item in result {
                    self.products.append(item as! Product)
                }

            } catch let error as NSError {
                print("Error happeend \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })

        case .Failure(let error):
            print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ProductCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ProductTableViewCell
    cell.productName.text = products[indexPath.row].name
    cell.percentage.text = "\(products[indexPath.row].percentage as? Double )"
    cell.quantity.text = "\(products[indexPath.row].quantity as? Int)"

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint so that you can examine the array?  I suggest you load your products into a local variable array and then assign this to `self.products` after the loop. Do you update `self.products` anywhere else? Do the rows show literally `nil` or are the cells just blank?  Have you set appropriate constraints on your cell contents?

Comment: @Paulw11 I've set breakpoints and there is data in the array at first, then after scrolling all the data turn to  `nil`  , and it shows `nil` in tableView. I didn't update `self.products` anywhere else.

Comment: Then it seems you are doing something to the array, but it isn't shown here. You should probably dispatch a tableview.reloadData on the main queue after the network fetch is complete

Comment: @Paulw11 I didn't update `self.products` anywhere else. I reload tableView on the main queue but still the same problem

Comment: Ok. On closer inspection I see you are putting core data NSManagedObjects in your array. Why are you doing this?  It seems likely the the managed object context is being reset. Just create a Product struct and use instances of that in your array

Comment: @Paulw11 Shouldn't it work with NSManagedObject subclass? Product is already a subclass of the entity's NSManagedObject.

Comment: Yes, but it isn't clear why you are using core data in this way. You never save the managed object context (at least not in the code shown) and if you were to save the context then you should retrieve the objects and compare them with those retrieved from the server in order to update your local copy.

Comment: @Paulw11 I updated my code above, it crashes on CellForRow delegate method. Something interesting is that right after fetching the newly added data, and still being inside that insertion when I put a breakpoint and check products local variable, the Products are there.. but in cellForRow, I get `<Basic_iOS_UI.Product: 0x7f80214c9080> (entity: <null>; id: 0xd0000000d18c0000 <x-coredata://CF953EF3-CF5E-414A-B80B-23622760AE7C/Product/p13411> ; data: <fault>)` instead!

Comment: That looks ok. That is a CoreData fault. The actual object will be fetched when you access the data, but again, why are you persisting the data through core data if you are just fetching the data from the network each time?

Comment: @Paulw11 Actually that's not all there is to it. For some reasons, we have to delete all the objects and retrieve data every time the view loads, but we need to persist the data for usage throughout the app and the view controller that's receiving the objects. I've ran out of ideas myself! Do you think it has anything to do with faulting?? Should NSFetchedResultController do the job?

Comment: There is no need to use core data to persist data during execution of the app. You only need that if you want to persist data between executions of the app. To make data available throughout the app during execution you can just use a data model object that holds the array. Either implement it as a singleton or pass it between object instances

Comment: @Paulw11 Well, the reason behind it is that the user might not have internet connection, therefore persistence of objects would come real handy. Using another data model object (a struct) would work as well, but seems more work as this doesn't seem to be wrong. I just don't get why it loads them fine at first, but it seems as though the local variable gets updated!

Comment: I can understand why you might want to persist a local copy, but your app isn't structured that way at the moment; to do that you would need to compare the data received from the network with that already in Core Data and add/delete as appropriate.  Something seems to be removing the objects from Core Data.  If you eliminate Core Data and just use a simple array of structs, then you can satisfy yourself that your basic table view controller is OK.